# mysql insert error 1062

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO  `website_categorization`.`category_keyword` (
`ID` ,
`ID_Category` ,
`Keyword` ,
`Score`)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '18',  'free mail',  ''
), (
NULL ,  '18',  'web email free',  ''
)
```

MySQL said:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '18-free mail' for key 'ID_Category'
```

It shows this duplicate entry error even though there is no entry at row  no 1062. ( ID is primary key, and unique(ID_Category,Keyword) ).
Can u help me in this?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have a row in your database with the values '18' and 'free mail'. You can't have two such rows because of the unique constraint. You have some choices:

- Remove the original row and try your insert again: `DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE ID_Category = '18' AND Keyword = 'free mail'`.
- Remove the unique constraint to allow both rows to exist.
- Use `INSERT IGNORE` to ignore the error.
- Use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT` to replace the old row with the new row.
- Attempt the `INSERT` knowing that the client-side will be alerted of the error.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it means that the data you are inserting breaks the unique constraints. From the error messasge I'd say some data already exists with the pair (18, 'free mail') - you say that is constrained to be unique.

The row number is not an indication, because it doesn't correspond to the key.

Answer (score 1):

That is MySQL Error number 1062, not row number. The error means duplicate entry. You are inserting NULL and '18' twice in ID and ID_Category respectively, so it will throw this error the 2nd time you do it. `ID_Category` is very likely the name of your index. You can do a

`show index from website_categorization.category_keyword`

to see the index name.

Answer (score 1):

Your ID_category key is declared as unique and thus you cannot have two entries with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ID` field is truly a primary key, it is mostly likely (or should be) auto-incremented. So leave that field out of the INSERT query.